# Looping Array Recursively to Create Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, javascript-objects

I'm seriously struggling to solve this algorithm.  I know the  solution will be recursive, but i'm stumped on how to solve this problem. Feel free to take a crack at it.  Thank you

Problem: ['a','b','c',['d','e','f',['g','h']], [i, j, k]]

```
Output:

{
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: true,
  d: {
   e: true,
   f: true,
   g: {
     h: true
   }
  },
   i: {
     j: true,
     k: true
   }
}
```

Comment: Following the OP's examlpe, a single building pattern, applied consequently, should start the nesting already at `a` ... `{ a: { b: true, c: true, d: { ... } ... } }`

Comment: I find it strange that you have marked an answer as accepted that provides Ruby code, when your question is tagged with `javascript` and `javascript-objects`. Did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.fromEntries` and feed it key/value pairs. When the "key" happens to be an array, use the first element as key, and perform recursion on the remainder of the array to get the value part:

```js
const toObject = arr =>
    Object.fromEntries(arr.map(item => Array.isArray(item)
        ? [item[0], toObject(item.slice(1))]
        : [item, true]
    ));

const arr = ["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e", "f", ["g", "h"]], ["i", "j", "k"]];
const result = toObject(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const convert = (arr = []) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, e) => {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      const [k, ...sub] = e;
      acc[k] = convert(sub);
    } else {
      acc[e] = true;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(
  convert(["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e", "f", ["g", "h"]], ["i", "j", "k"]])
);
```

Comment: Thanks @MajedBadawi, Oh  I see so you were able to use reduce with an empty object to accumulate the first level of the array and then subsequently apply a recursion to the elements identified as an array. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby (think pseudo-code).

```
def recurse(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |e,h|
    case e
    when String
      h[e.to_sym] = true
    else # Array
      h[e.first.to_sym] = recurse(e.drop(1))
    end
  end
end
```

Suppose (slightly changed from example in question)

```
arr = ['a','b','c',['d','e','f',['g','h', ['m', 'n']]], ['i', 'j', 'k']]
```

Then

```
recurse arr
  #=> {
  #     :a=>true,
  #     :b=>true,
  #     :c=>true,
  #     :d=> {
  #       :e=>true,
  #       :f=>true,
  #       :g=>{
  #       :h=>true,
  #         :m=>{
  #         :n=>true
  #       }
  #     }
  #   },
  #   :i=>{
  #     :j=>true,
  #     :k=>true
  #   }
  # }
```